# Download CSV file on click event of link button not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below piece of code is not working. I want to download a CSV file from the folder on link button click event.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string filePath = "~/Data/Book1.csv";
  System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(filePath));
  if (file.Exists)
  {
    WebClient req = new WebClient();
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    //string filePath = "";
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Filename.extension");
    byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(filePath));
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();   
  }
}
```

Comment: `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; Filename=" + file.Name + "");`

Comment: You can try with the code i posted.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an exception? Is the file not transferred to the client? Why do you use `WebClient` to read the file?

Comment: instead of AddHeader it should be appendHeader???

Comment: Ok i got your point of say.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the file by using a `WebClient`, you can transmit it to the client directly. As long as the file is located in the local file system, you do not need to get it using a web request but can read it directly. This is much more efficient.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string filePath = "~/Data/Book1.csv";
  System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(filePath));
  if (file.Exists)
  {
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=" + file.Name);
    response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();   
  }
}
```

I'd also recomment to disable buffer and to flush the content before ending the response.

As also @BobSwager pointed out, there are some problems in the `Content-Disposition` header.